# Get package names for dynamic sets in Gentoo Linux

Tags: linux, gentoo

I would like to get a list of e.g. all the live (i.e. version `9999`) packages on my Gentoo Linux system.
These are contained in the (dynamically generated) `@live-rebuild` package set.

I can have them printed to screen by running `emerge -pav @live-rebuild`; but this also gives me a lot of other details and syntax:

```
zenbookhost ~ # emerge -pav @live-rebuild

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R   *] sci-libs/nipy-9999::neurogentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 -python3_5" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] app-misc/repositorg-9999::chymeric  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R    ] dev-python/yahoo-finance-9999::chymeric  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 -python3_5" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] sci-biology/ants-9999::neurogentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] sci-libs/labbookdb-9999::chymeric  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 -python3_5" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] dev-python/matrix2latex-9999::neurogentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] dev-python/tqdm-9999::gentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 -python3_5" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] sci-biology/psychopy-9999::neurogentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] sci-biology/nilearn-9999::neurogentoo  USE="plot {-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 -python3_5" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] sci-biology/dcmstack-9999::neurogentoo  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 -python3_5" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R   *] sci-visualization/mricron-9999::neurogentoo  0 KiB

Total: 11 packages (11 reinstalls), Size of downloads: 0 KiB
```

Is there any way to get just the `category/package` names - as I would by running `cat /var/lib/portage/world`? For the above that would be:

```
sci-libs/nipy
app-misc/repositorg
```

and so on.

Ideally I would be looking for a parameter of the `emerge` command, which just returns the package names, or some file where these sets are saved (like `/var/lib/portage/world`).

Comment: Can you post the output of `emerge -pav @live-rebuild` ? Do you want an actual command to list as per your requirement or happy to use other shell utilities to get the desired result.

Comment: What is your expected output from the above output that you have shared?

Comment: an addtional pipline to `sed` can easily filter any line matching `[ebuild`. Does that give you the output you need? Good luck.

Comment: Were you able to make my solution work? Care to provide feedback on it?

Answer (score 3):

If you have `GNU grep` you can use its `-P` flag for [`PCRE mode`](http://www.pcre.org) and `-o` for match-only pattern,

```
emerge -pav @live-rebuild | grep -Po "\[.*\]\s\K[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\/[a-zA-Z]*"
sci-libs/nipy
app-misc/repositorg
dev-python/yahoo
sci-biology/ants
sci-libs/labbookdb
dev-python/matrix
dev-python/tqdm
sci-biology/psychopy
sci-biology/nilearn
sci-biology/dcmstack
sci-visualization/mricron
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but Ideally I was looking for a way to get this directly from Portage. Either via `emerge` or perhaps if it is stored somewhere on the file system.